# Javascript Regex not passing test string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using javascript regex to test a string. It should fail the text string but somehow its passing it. Any clue, what is wrong with this code?

```
<script>
var format = "^[a-zA-Z\.\-' ]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\.\-' ]*";
var testingValue = "FN306716";
var regex = new RegExp(format);
if (regex.test(testingValue) == false) { 
alert('validation failed');
}
else {
alert('validation passed');
}
</script>
```

Comment: why do you expect it should fail?

Comment: what do you expect the regex to do ?

Comment: On the Web have javascript regex examples. [sample regex](http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/basic-javascript-regular-expression/)

Comment: Your backslashes need to be escaped, otherwise your setup causes an error. This wouldn't happen if you were using a regex literal

Comment: @Ian - The backslashes are not even necessary since they are in character classes (in positions where the special characters they are escaping don't have any special meaning).

Comment: @JamesAllardice but the range `.` to `'` (`.-'`)  is not valid, which results in an error.

Comment: @t.niese - oh yeah, you're right. Moving the `-` around could remove the need for the escape characters though.

Comment: @JamesAllardice That's not my point, but still true. The `-` could be put at the end, but to me it's more readable if it's escaped (no matter where it is). As for the `.` - I can't see a reason why you'd need to escape it, but I think jslint complains if you don't (just saying)

Comment: @Ian - Good point about JSLint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing that you are missing `$` at the end of your regex to test full string.

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\.\-' ]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\.\-' ]$/;
```

With this regex, your input wouldn't pass, because it contains numbers.

EDIT: I have updated it to use regex literal as pointed out in comments.

Comment: This is still not a valid `RegExp`, either write `/^[a-zA-Z\.\-' ]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\.\-' ]$/` to get a `RegExp` directly or escape the `\ ` because the string is another _layer_ to the way to the `RegExp` otherwise you have a range `.-'` which is not valid.

Comment: Just a note: The `new RegExp` is not required there. The `/something/i` is a shortcut for `new RegExp("something","i")`. I don't want to say that writing it that way is wrong, just want to note that it is not required.

Comment: No this is not working... I want a regex that allow only following set of character in my string. [a-z] [A-Z] and following four special character [.]dot [']apostrophe [ ]space [-]hyphen. Regex should check that at least one character a-z or A-Z is entered otherwise it should fail.

Comment: I want a regex that allow only following set of character in my string. [a-z] [A-Z] and following four special character [.]dot [']apostrophe [ ]space [-]hyphen. Regex should check that at least one character a-z or A-Z is entered otherwise it should fail.

Comment: @MichalKlouda Your edit still didn't fix the regex. With a literal, you don't instantiate it with `RegExp` - it's by itself. When you use `RegExp`, you put the regex in a string, and you have to escape all backslashes

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `$` (end of input anchor):

Regex should be:

```
var format = "^[a-zA-Z.' -]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z.' -]*$";
```

Also remember that `-` need not be escaped when used at fist and last position in character class and dot `.` also need not be escaped inside character class.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/Q26cgQVJTm